# Доступность сервера на Debian в локальной сети

Tags: debian, ip, lan

Сервер на Debian 9 не пингуется в локальной сети маршрутизатора, внешние ip адреса и адрес шлюза пингуется, другие устройства находящиеся в локальной сети не пингуются, так же сервер не доступен с устройств находящихся в одной с ним подсети по любым портам и тоже не пингуется. С внешнего адреса сервер пингуется. Сеть состоит из G PON модема со встроенным маршрутизатором. На модем настроен проброс портов с внешнего ip. Имеется статический IP который и пробрасывается. Помогите кто знает решить вопрос как заставить сервер быть виден не только из вне но и в своей подсети.
etc/network/interfaces       выглядит так

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug enp6s0
#auto enp6s0
#iface enp6s0 inet dhcp

auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet static
address 192.168.100.9
gateway 192.168.100.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

iptables -nvL --line-numbers

```
root@paratrooper2:~# iptables -nvL --line-numbers
```

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 106 packets, 5553 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1     846K  118M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
2     846K  118M ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
3     1769  247K ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0                                                                                        .0.0.0/0
4      106  5553 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
5      106  5553 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
6      106  5553 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0                                                                                        .0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
4        0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
5        0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
6        0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 309 packets, 20314 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1     973K 2015M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
2     973K 2015M ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
3     1320 86880 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
4     1320 86880 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
5     1320 86880 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0
6     1320 86880 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1       12  1344 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0
2     823K  117M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3     3246  239K ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
4     3246  239K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ctstate INVALID
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 3
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 11
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 12
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 8
9        2  1152 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
10   20018 1330K ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0                                                                                        .0.0/0
11       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0                                                                                        .251          udp dpt:5353
12       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255                                                                                        .255.250      udp dpt:1900
13   20018 1330K ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.                                                                                        0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1       12  1344 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0
2     971K 2015M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3     1320 86880 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0                                                                                        .0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 3
3        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 11
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 12
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            icmptype 8
6        0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1      171 15066 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
2        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
3        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
4        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
5        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
6        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
7     1492  227K ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1      106  5553 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK]                                                                                         "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK]                                                                                         "

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1      269 18852 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ctstate NEW
2      742 47714 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1     1855  174K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
2      596 27955 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK]                                                                                         "

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW]                                                                                         "

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1     1663  242K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1    18355 1089K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2        0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
3     1663  242K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
4        0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
5        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1     4417  264K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:22 /* 'dapp_SSH' */
2      998 52670 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:80
3    12698  759K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:443
4       13   612 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:10000
5        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            udp dpt:10000
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:20
7       70  3952 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:21
8        8   671 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            multiport dports 30000:31000
9       45  1984 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            multiport dports 30000:31000
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:25
11       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            tcp dpt:10000

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BL                                                                                        OCK] "
2        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                                                                        tion
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0                                                                                        /0

iptables -nvL --line-numbers -t nat

```
root@paratrooper2:~# iptables -nvL --line-numbers -t nat
```

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: Ваш сервис (порт какой?) доступен, на сервере Debian  из вне, и не доступен по локальной сети. Правильно? Нужны настройки firewall. Из под root, iptables -nvL --line-numbers и iptables -nvL --line-numbers -t nat две команды что показывают? И к Debian-у вы по имени или по адресу обращаетесь?

Comment: Ваш сервис (порт какой?) доступен, на сервере Debian из вне, и не доступен по локальной сети.  По 80 порту и по  ICMP  из вне доступен, а в локальной сети нет!

Comment: По адресу обращаюсь

Comment: Вывод команд очень большой что искать нужно?